# Are enumerated type implementations located inside or outside the Class implementation

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, enums

Currently I have this code for my underlying model:

```
Public Enum vehicleType
    Car
    Lorry
    Bicycle
End Enum
Public Class TrafficSurveyA
    ' Declare the fields here.
    Private fCars As Integer
    Private fBicycles As Integer
    Private fLorries As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        ' An instance of TrafficSurveyA is created with all vehicle counts set to zero.
        fCars = 0
        fBicycles = 0
        fLorries = 0
    End Sub
    Public Sub incrementCount(ByVal vehicle As vehicleType)
        ' Preconditions: none
        ' Postconditions: If vehicle is "Car", "Bicycle" or "Lorry" then 1 is added
        ' to the corresponding count. Otherwise nothing is done.

        Select Case vehicle
            Case vehicleType.Car : fCars = fCars + 1
            Case vehicleType.Bicycle : fBicycles = fBicycles + 1
            Case vehicleType.Lorry : fLorries = fLorries + 1
            Case Else 'do nothing
        End Select
    End Sub

    Public Function getCount(ByVal vehicle As vehicleType) As String
        ' Preconditions: none
        ' Postconditions: If vehicle is "Car", "Bicycle" or "Lorry", the string
        ' representation of the corresponding count is returned.
        ' Otherwise the empty string is returned.

        Dim result As String
        result = ""
        Select Case vehicle
            Case vehicleType.Car : result = Convert.ToString(fCars)
            Case vehicleType.Bicycle : result = Convert.ToString(fBicycles)
            Case vehicleType.Lorry : result = Convert.ToString(fLorries)
            Case Else : result = ""
        End Select
        Return result
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Vehicles() As String
        ' Preconditions: none
        ' Postconditions: The total number of vehicles recorded is returned.
        Get
            Return (fCars + fBicycles + fLorries).ToString()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

It seems that the `Enum` could just as easily be placed within the `TrafficSurveyA` Class like so...

```
Public Class TrafficSurveyA

    Enum vehicleType
        Car
        Lorry
        Bicycle
    End Enum

    ' Declare the fields here.
    Private fCars As Integer
    Private fBicycles As Integer
    Private fLorries As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        ' An instance of TrafficSurveyA is created with all vehicle counts set to zero.
        fCars = 0
        fBicycles = 0
        fLorries = 0
    End Sub
    ...
    ...
```

The only difference then seems to be in the GUI code I need to use this `TrafficSurveyA.vehicleType.Lorry` rather than this `vehicleType.Lorry`.

Both seem to run ok but is one of these implementations of the enum type wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, both are fine. It's just a matter of preference and what makes the most sense for organization purposes. The only suggestion I have is that if the enum will be used as a input or output type in any other classes, I wouldn't put it inside this class. That would just be confusing.

Comment: +1 cheers Steven. I've got another simple `enum` question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013227/converting-enum-type-to-a-sting-in-order-to-return-the-name).

Answer (score 1):

None of the options are wrong, but public nested types (like the enum declared inside the class) are generally discouraged. They can be confusing to clients who have to qualify them with the outer class name. Look at the related guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229027(v=vs.100).aspx). Some that are relevant:

> Do not use public nested types as a logical grouping construct; use namespaces for this.
>
> Avoid publicly exposed nested types. The only exception to this is when variables of the nested type need to be declared in rare scenarios such as subclassing or other advanced customization scenarios.
>
> Do not use nested types if the type is likely to be referenced outside of the declaring type.

Comment: ahhh - so a _Class_ is effectively a _type_ + an _enum_ is also a _type_. Therefore when I put the `enum` inside the `Class` I'm actually _nesting types_; I'll avoid this in the future.

Comment: @whytheq: note that this is a _guideline_, there might be perfectly good reasons to use nested types.

Answer (score 0):

Also think of limiting the scope to the narrowest range:

- Private only used inside of a class
- Friend used inside of assembly
- Public can be access any project or assembly built from this project

[Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx)