# CStr() compared with .ToString when dealing with an Enum type

Tags: vb.net

I (obviously incorrectly) had assumed that `Cstr(something)` was equivalent to `something.ToString`.
I wanted to get hold of an enumerated type as a string and it seems depending on which conversion method I use I either get the index of the `enum` or the name:

```
Public Enum vehicleType
    Car
    Lorry
    Bicycle
End Enum

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("Index is " & _
               CStr(vehicleType.Car) & _
               ".Name is " & _
               vehicleType.Car.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why are these conversions to string returning different elements of the `enum` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ToString` method is a standard public method that returns a `String`. It is a method that is defined by the base `Object` type as overrideable. Each class can, therefore, override that method to return anything that it wants.  It is quite common for classes to override the `ToString` method to make it return a nice human-readable description of the object.

`CStr`, on the other hand, is a casting operator. It is shorthand for `CType(x, String)`. The casting operator, like many other operators, can be overridden by any class.  Normally, though, you want casting operations to return the closest representation of the actual value of the original object, rather than a descriptive string.

It is not unusual then, that you may want `ToString` to return a different result than `CStr`. In the case of an enum, each member is essentially an Integer, so `CStr` on an enum member works the same as `CStr` on an integer. That is what you would expect. However, `ToString` has been overridden to return the more human readable version of the value. That is also what you would expect.

Here's an example of a class that overrides both `CStr` and `ToString`:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Overrides Function ToString()
        Return "Result from ToString"
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal p1 As MyClass) As String
        Return "Result from cast to String"
    End Operator
End Class
```

Comment: +1 excellent - thanks again. Didn't realise that `CStr, CInt ...etc` are short versions of `CType`.

Comment: Sorry for my formatting. I wanted to provide an example of overriding both in one class too, but I'm on my phone in the car, so it's too difficult. I'll try to fix it up later (unless someone wants to lend me a hand and fix it for me first :)

Comment: ...no rush Steve - I look forward to the extra info; `SO` on your phone in the car ....`SO` is dangerously addictive!!

Comment: Ha!  That is a funny mental image! No, my wife's driving. I broke my right foot, so I can't drive with the cast on. But if I was driving, I may still have felt the urge to type about casting operator overloading. I may have made my wife type it for me!

Comment: There you go. It's now a bit closer to my exacting standards. Still from my phone, but from the house instead of the car :)

Comment: ...like your style steven. p.s you don't seem to have a Christmas hat?

Comment: :) no, I got tired of being alerted about hats so I told SO that "I hate hats" and they all went away. I've been much happier ever since. My Grado SR-125 headphones already make the perfect hat. I don't need any digitized hat apparel to make my profile pic more festive. My pic is already perfect. I've never been told so, but I suspect it's the envy of everyone who sees it.

Answer (score 1):

What type of expressions CStr() accepts is explained in detail in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch47ss2a.aspx).  Summarizing:

- An expression that produces a Boolean, converted to "True" or "False"
- An expression that produces a DateTime, converted to the short datetime format
- An expression that produces a numeric type, converted to a string that represents the number.

Do note that it doesn't have a bullet for enumerated types. The compiler is always happy to convert an enum value to an integer.  So the 3rd bullet applies and this is why you get "0".

Comment: +1 - also - the code I'm using to get the name used for the enum is correct `vehicleType.Car.ToString` ?